# android mqtt-client-1.5 listener with apollo

Tags: android, mqtt, apollo

https://github.com/fusesource/mqtt-client

i have an android application starting a background service where i have initiated an mqtt connection towards an apollo broker. when startService is called im initiating the MQTT from the onStartCommand setting hostname, port username, password etc.. followed by

```
connection = mqtt.callbackConnection();
```

the connect is successfull and i can clearly see that i have  a consumer on my topic "uniqueId".

But when i send messages to my topic , the listener never calles the **onPublish**.. Another strange occurence is that if i loose my connection towards the broker , e.g i shut down the broker so that the active connection is broken, when the mqtt-client reconnects, it seems that it calles the listener and also the onPublish because then all the messages that i have stacked on my durable subscriber topic is delivered.. am i missing anything here regarding the listener?

isnt it suppose to actively consume the topic due to connection.subscribe??

```
Topic[] topics = { new Topic("uniqueId", QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE) };
connection.subscribe(topics, new Callback<byte[]>() {
    public void onSuccess(byte[] qoses) {
    }
    public void onFailure(Throwable value) {
        value.printStackTrace();
    }
});

connection.listener(new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnected() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable value) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onPublish(UTF8Buffer topic, Buffer payload, Runnable ack) {
        ack.run();
    }
});
```

Comment: seems to be working on both activemq and mosquitto.. anyone experienced this problem with apollo specifically?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Apollo, but I agree that the behaviour sounds incorrect. You could try testing against another broker to see if it works as expected, then file a bug against Apollo if necessary.

You could use e.g. test.mosquitto.org:1883 to test against, or use one of the other public ones listed on mqtt.org/software

Comment: actually i did test it against activemq 5.8.0 just now, and it seems to be working there. im guessing it has something to do on the messages being sent to the topic, or that its a bug on apollo